# Maps on a website

Tags: html, css, mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am working on a land parcels management system. The website is offering search services for land parcels. I am trying to integrate the website with maps. A person can search for a piece of land using an available land ownership document number such as a title deed, and then, the website locates the piece of land on the map and displays the relevant information.

I have the option of archGIS, but I can't figure out how to create the maps and convert the map data into database variables and database variables into mapd. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible, you can do one thing, I can show you how to insert maps in a website using Google Maps though, not ArchGIS.

First, you should make a web-page of how many land you have and when the user clicks on the link it will make a new page where you can show the map you want. Or else you could create some rows and columns and insert the map there but the first one is a lot easier for you.

Alright, now you have to go to Google Maps and search the place of which you want to insert in your web-site then click 'Share' which will be available on the left, a new window will open, then click on Embed a map.

Then a code like this will generate = `'<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3681.9191333728836!2d88.41682721453802!3d22.65680348513951!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39f89e60501dda2d%3A0x2698d72c277affc7!2sOneSolution%2CBirati!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1527664105639" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'`

Paste it in your website and the map will be visible.

Comment: Let me try that. But i wanted the maps to be dynamic... the land can change shape after splitting. And the crucial part is to display the actual data a person is looking for when buying land that is.. the actual land size, shape and location.. but i can try figure that out but i welcome more suggestions. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: Sorry, I am not that professional in this as I am only 14 years old, but you can Google a bit for help, you can get a lot of help there.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific like do you want to add some markers in the map or do you want to show all of your land on the map or show one or more locations on one map.

Comment: What i mean is It should display one piece of land at a time and indicate its boarders too.

Comment: Yes like that but i will add some addational feature for exact location

Comment: Like? Please explain, is it like when a user will click on that location, it will display the details. You can do that.

Comment: More streets and maybe physical/natural featurs that can help locate the place although the initial thought was to use gps but its already complicated for me so far so i will just use something simple. Please explain how to go about your design

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Use Google MyMaps for my design, you can get it how to do it, it is very straightforward. and you can add physical/natural features as per my knowledge though it is somewhat advanced.